# C++ Searching a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I have a program that takes in a data file of students that have a COSID between 100 and 200 and the courses they are enrolled in. It looks like : `100
Greg 
Samson
3
COS301
COS431
COS490
120
Jo Ann
Lyons
0`. I  have a dynamic array that holds all the courses that the student is taking. The problem that I am having is I am asked to print other people in a paticular class when a course ID is inputed using this prototype: `void printList (ostream& out,  FlexArray<Student> majors,  int cosID, string course);`

I'm not really sure how to create the function to search the array for this protype. I tried to intilize the array so all the COSID's are -1 so when trying to search I should be more easily able to find the elements that have information, but can't get that work either. Here is my code thus far T:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "templates.h"


using namespace std;

struct Student {

  int COSID;
  string fname;
  string lname;
  int totCourses;
   string * coursearr;
};
void printList (ostream& out,  FlexArray<Student> majors,  int cosID, string course);

int main(){
    Student s; // Object for struct student
    int searchCOSID; //varible to find COS id
    int Loopcheck = -1; //break loop variable
    string LoopCOSID = ""; //break loop variable
    FlexArray<Student> fa(100,200); //object for flex array setting Upper bounds to 200 and lower bounds to 100

    //Initilize the flexarray cosid to -1;
    for(int i=100; i<=200; i++){
        fa[s.COSID = -1];
    }
    cout << fa[105].COSID;
    char c;


    ifstream  fin;              // declare input file stream object 
    fin.open ("a5.txt");
    fin >> s.COSID;
    fin.get(c);
    getline(fin, s.fname);
    getline(fin, s.lname);
    fin >> s.totCourses;
    while(!fin.fail()){
        s.coursearr = new string[s.totCourses];
        if(s.totCourses > 0){
        for(int i=0; i<s.totCourses; i++){
            fin >> s.coursearr[i];
        }
        }
        fa[s.COSID] = s;
        fin >> s.COSID;
        fin.get(c);
        getline(fin, s.fname);
        getline(fin, s.lname);
        fin >> s.totCourses;
    }



        cout << "\nEnter your COS ID: ";
        cin >> searchCOSID;
        Student currstudent = fa[searchCOSID];
        if(currstudent.COSID=-1){
            cout << "ID not asscoaited with a student";
        }else{
            cout << "The courses taken this semester by " << currstudent.fname  << " " << currstudent.lname << " include:";
            if(currstudent.totCourses > 0){
                for(int i=0; i<currstudent.totCourses;i++){
                cout << "\n" << currstudent.coursearr[i];
                }
            }
            else{cout << endl <<"No courses";}
        }



    while(Loopcheck == -1){
        cout << "\n\nEnter a couses (Q) to quit: ";
        cin >> LoopCOSID;
        if(LoopCOSID == "Q" || LoopCOSID=="q"){
            Loopcheck = 0;
        }else{
            string course;
            cout << endl << "Other students taking this course include: ";
            //printList(cout,FlexArray<Student>,searchCOSID,coursearr);
        }

    }
    return 0;


}

void printList (ostream& out,  FlexArray<Student> majors,  int cosID, string course){
    for (int i = 0; i<101; i++){

    }


}
```

Comment: It's a dynamic array, right? Why not search like you'd search any other array -- loop through and do comparisons.

Comment: I don't know where `FlexArray` comes from, but surely it provides a way to iterate over its data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For each student s in majors (silly name for a list of students isn't it?)
   if s.COSID is not cosID
       for each class c that s is taking
           if c equals course
               display s.fname
```

I think.  It's hard to tell.  `print other people in a paticular class when a course ID is inputed using this prototype: void printList (ostream& out, FlexArray<Student> majors, int cosID, string course);`  Does this mean print all the students who are taking `course`, except for that who's `COSID` is the `cosID` parameter?

Comment: ` Does this mean print all the students who are taking course, except for that who's COSID is the cosID parameter?`  Yes, exactly.

Comment: What should the first forloop i< (?) be? This is what I have ``Student s;
 for (int i = 0; i<101; i++){
  if(s.COSID != cosID){
   for(int j=0; j<=s.totCourses ;j++){
    if(s.coursearr[j] == course){
     cout << "\n" << s.fname << " " << s.lname;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 ``

Comment: In your case the first for loop is `for(int i=0; i<101; ++i) if(courses[i].COSID != -1) { ...`  You will have to check if the students exist.  Your code also didn't assign `s`.